# Convert one column to multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert data in one column (say column A) to multiple rows and the results would be started in D1. This is the code till now

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a, e, ws As Worksheet, x As Long, i As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    a = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
    ReDim b(1 To UBound(a) / 5, 1 To 5)
    For Each e In a
        If x Mod 5 = 0 Then i = i + 1: x = 0
        x = x + 1
        b(i, x) = e
    Next e
    ws.Range("D1").Resize(UBound(b), 5) = b
End Sub
```

When the data counts as number accepts the division by 5 the code works fine. But if the number doesn't accept the division by 5 the code throws an error. How can I overcome this point?
I need the extra items to go to new row even if it is one item.

Comment: You mean like `num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling_Math(UBound(a) / 5, 1)` and then `ReDim b(1 To num, 1 To 5)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to round a number up to the nearest integer then use the `Ceiling.Math` worksheet function from your VBA code. You can read about it in [CEILING.MATH function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ceiling-math-function-80f95d2f-b499-4eee-9f16-f795a8e306c8) and [WorksheetFunction.Ceiling method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.ceiling)

You can also use [Ceiling_Precise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.ceiling_precise)

Try this

```
num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling_Math(UBound(a) / 5, 1)
ReDim b(1 To num, 1 To 5)
```